# JAVA sin() output value to radians/degrees

Tags: java, type-conversion, trigonometry, degrees, radians

I have this problem: I know **Math.sin(someUnknownFloatValue)** output value and I really need to know how just from this single Math.sin() output **find out what was that actual "someUnknownFloatNumber" that created it** - is it possible, isn't there already some Math function that convert this sin() output to degrees/radians?

Comment: are u looking for `asin()` method ??

Comment: If only there were [some online site where you could look this stuff up](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#asin-double-)..... such as the [Math API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)....  if only.

Comment: actually I was looking for it all over th eplace but Google did not give me that output you are giving me, strange, if it is such obvious task, isn;t it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:  Maybe this is more of a trigonometry question.  Many may not know about the [inverse trig functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) out there.

Comment: @Makoto: perhaps, but wikipedia would quickly clarify this up for the OP. I'm a bit surprised though that the original poster didn't look through the Math API before coming here, since that is the source of the sin and cos methods and all similar methods. His search skills seem to need some practice.

Comment: @errerr I would be looking for a function that is the inverse of the sine function. google would tell you it's the arcsine in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I am not experienced JAVA user nor mathematician + english is not my native language, so I know what I want to solve but because of the things I said above I am not able to help myself therefore I came here for help from experienced users, yet ppl like you ar ebasically saying "Unless you have decree in physics do not ask questions cos they may sound stupid to us!" - WTF?! The world is in shit because of arrogant ppl like you - you did no thelp me a bit, only being sarcastic and arrogant, bad behaviour.

Comment: OK, sorry for the sarcasm, but seriously how hard is it to Google, [java math inverse sine](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java%20math%20inverse%20sine) before asking your question? I'm not asking you to be a math or programming major, but it wouldn't hurt for you to show some evidence of effort with your question. You could have stated, I Googled such and such, examined XXX site, but am confused by the statement, "....". Something, anything that shows that you've at least tried something to solve your problem first. That's all I'm asking, and it truly isn't asking too much

Comment: Don't you understand still? HOW COULD I KNOW I AM LOOKING FOR INVERSE SINE() VERSION when I had no clue what function I am looking for in the firs tplace? As I said I am  not that good in mathematics...

Comment: + what merit it would have saying "I was Googling for it but did not find it..."? I think this is automatically assumption that I already did cos I would not be here then, right? ;-) Anyway: problem solved, so thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arcsine is the inverse sine function that you are looking for. In Java, this would be `asin()`.

Comment: YES: this seems to be the right and STRAIGHT FORWARD answer/Math function I was looking for without giving me some irony or sarcasm as others did instead which was absolutely unnecessary as it did not help me at all, thanx! I would just add maybe for some other guys that are not that experienced in JAVA (just like me) that one has to convert that asin() output to degrees with Math.toDegreees() function.

Answer (score 2):

use `Math.toRadians` and `Math.toDegrees`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Math.asin`, which calculates the arcsine of a value.

```
public class Test{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double radians = Math.asin(0.5);
        double degrees = Math.toDegrees(radians);
        assert degrees > 29.999 && degrees < 30.001;
    }
}
```

It will map to an angle θ, 0° ≤ θ < 360°, e.g. arcsine(sine(375°)) ≠ 375°

Answer (score 0):

The answers above will give you the **VALUE** of the parameter that went into your Math.sin() function call. However if you actually need access to the parameter itself, (so you can modify before/after execution etc etc), you should trace the execution call to where the Math.sin function was invoked and see what was passed into it. That will lead you to the actual original input value in whatever form it may have been.

Comment: Actually I am solving some 4x3 Matrix rotation values that are there but not as actual angles, but in float numbers, I have access to function that rotates on Y (what I actually need) and I needed to do kind of reverse engeneering, that is: I know all the variables except the one that actually came to that function which is actual rotation for the object in degrees that I need to find out. :-) + Sorry for my bad english, it is not my native language as you can see so I hope you understand what I am writing...